# StackOverflowError occurs multiple times

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

I was trying out this piece of code to understand exactly when a StackOverflowError occurs and how it behaves.

```
private static int testFunc(int i) {
    return i+1;
}

private static int add(int a){
    try {
        a = add(a);
    } catch(StackOverflowError e){
        System.out.println("StackOverflowError");
        return ++a;
    }
    return ++a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    char c = 'A';
    System.out.println((char)testFunc(c));
    int a = 0;
    System.out.println(add(a)); 
}
```

when I tried executing this code, I expected the recursion to stop when StackOverflowError occurs and the value printed to be one more than the depth of the available stack. But the StackOverflowError was caught multiple times. 
I got `StackOverflowErrorStackOverflowErrorStackOverflowError....` printed about a 11 times. Although I used a `System.out.println()` statement, everything was printed on a single line. and the output printed was 0. it was printed only once.

Also, when I included a `Thread.sleep(1000);` statement inside the catch block, to identify why I was getting such a bizarre output, I got an even more weird output. The print statement inside the catch block was executed several times. Maybe more than 100, I dont have an exact count. Here, in the first few print statement execution(first 7-8 executions), everything was printed on the same line, after that everything was printed on a new line. But the overall wait time was at one second (due to the 1000ms sleep time) and the output was still 0.

Why do I get such an output and why does StackOverflowError works in this way?

UPDATE: I just realized I had a few more lines on my original code, which creates this behavior. Updated the code.
Here is the actual output I got without the `Thread.sleep(1000)` statement.

```
B
stackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowError
0
```

UPDATE 2: I used the pre increment operator instead of the post increment operator and now I am getting a proper output for the stack depth. But if I remove the call to the testFunc(), the `StackOverflowError` statement is being printed only once before the stack depth is printed. But if I have those calls, it is being printed multiple times. Why is that so?

Comment: I just got `StackOverflowError
0
`

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: @ShanuGupta I have updated my question with my actual output. I also made changes to the code, as the testFunc() is causing this behavior.

Comment: hehe, for sure `B
stackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowErrorstackOverflowError
0` is not the whole stacktrace which you are getting :), please provide the whole message

Comment: You are calling add method recursively so when a stack overflow error occurred you are returning the current stack value of a to add method which will start recursive again and another stackoverflow process continues

Comment: Really weird...

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx I am not printing the stacktrace on my code I am printing just that statement. So this is the output I get.

Comment: Ah, you are printing it manually, sorry I did not notice, strange string to print :D. Then you can change it to `e.printstacktrace()` and you will see / get more clues what happened

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx `B
Exception in thread "main"
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"` this is the exception I get. Again, a totally unexpected Exception is thrown. Weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why multiple prints**

`System.out.println("StackOverflowError");` will call other methods internally, which will cause another `StackOverflowError` to be thrown. This happens after "StackOverflowError" was printed, but before the new line was printed.

**Why sometimes only one print**

The above explanation is a bit simplified. Actually it really depends on how much size is left on the stack after the first `StackOverflowError` was caught. Depending on the initial space left on your stack when starting the recursion, and on the amount of data each recursion adds to the stack, `println()` will behave differently:

- If enough space is on the stack for a call to `println()`:

  - You will get exactly one "StackOverflowError" in your console.
- If there is not enough space on the stack for a call to `println()`:

  - Either the call will throw before "StackOverflowError" was printed,
  - Or the call will throw after "StackOverflowError" was printed, but before the new line was printed,
  - Or the call will throw after "StackOverflowError" and the new line was printed.

This will then repeat until you're far enough down the recursion for `println()` to be called without an exception. So you can have 3 different outputs:

- One "StackOverflowError" with a new line,
- Multiple "StackOverflowError" with one new line,
- Multiple "StackOverflowError" with multiple new lines.

In each case you might've gotten more exceptions than occurrences of "StackOverflowError" in your console.

Which result you get is totally undetermined.

**Why 0**

Because you use the post increment operator, therefore you always return 0.

Comment: was very stupid on the post increment operator. I am getting a proper number when i changed it to pre Increment.

Comment: When I remove the call to the testFunc() method, the print statement inside the catch statement is executed only once. Why is that so?

Comment: Because by changing your main method you change the initial size of the stack. I would guess that now the stack size exceeds its limit at a point where after going back one recursion the `println()` call doesn't throw anymore.

Comment: Also.. shouldn't the second `StackOverflowError` be an uncaught exception?

Comment: No, why would it? Every recursion has its own try-catch block.

Comment: Ohh okay.. I get your point, but why does the program reach such a state?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What state?

Comment: In one case the `println()` statement throws more `StackOverflowError` but it doesn't in the other. Even if the initial stack size changes, the error must be thrown at a lower level, say after 1000 recursion a, instead of 1005 recursions (just a sample case..) but the behaviour should be the same right? i.e the `println()` function should still be throwing. I don't know much about the Java Stack and Heap. According to my current understanding, both the cases should either throw more errors or not throw. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Ohh.. interesting behaviour. This helps a lot. Thank you so much. Accepted the answer.